# Creating functions in sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am creating a function in oracle sql plus, that take empno as argument and returns its salary. But its not being created, where am I going wrong?

Here is my function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GETEMPSALARY (EMPNUMBER IN INTEGER) RETURN INTEGER
IS
EMPSALARY INTEGER;
BEGIN
SELECT SAL INTO EMPSALARY FROM EMP WHERE EMP.EMPNO = EMPNUMBER;
RETURN EMPSALARY;
END GETEMPSALARY;
```

Here is the error:

```
Error at line 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:

   . @ % ; is authid as cluster order using external character
   deterministic parallel_enable pipelined aggregate
   result_cache


1. CREATE FUNCTION GETNAMES1 (EMPID IN INTEGER) RETURN VARCHAR(20)
2. IS
3. EMPNAME VARCHAR(50);
```

Answer (score 1):

your missing the / at the end.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GETEMPSALARY (EMPNUMBER IN INTEGER) RETURN INTEGER
IS
DECLARE
EMPSALARY INTEGER;
BEGIN
SELECT SAL INTO EMPSALARY FROM EMP WHERE EMP.EMPNO = EMPNUMBER;
RETURN EMPSALARY;
END GETEMPSALARY;
/
```

edit: 
due to your new error which is on a totally different function!

```
CREATE FUNCTION GETNAMES1 (EMPID IN INTEGER) RETURN VARCHAR(20)
```

you shouldnt specifiy a precision on returns, so put

```
 RETURN VARCHAR2
```

also dont use `VARCHAR`, only `VARCHAR2`

and for statement ignored;

```
SQL> CREATE FUNCTION GETEMPSALARY (EMPNUMBER IN INTEGER) RETURN INTEGER
  2  IS
  3  EMPSALARY INTEGER;
  4  BEGIN
  5  SELECT SAL INTO EMPSALARY FROM EMP WHERE EMP.EMPNO = EMPNUMBER;
  6  RETURN EMPSALARY;
  7  END GETEMPSALARY;
  8  /

Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for FUNCTION GETEMPSALARY:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
5/32     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
SQL>
```

what is the subsequent error you see, as this error should be followed by a real error

Comment: @user1844205 ok thats not the same function you pasted change `return varchar2(20)` to `return varchar2`. you don't have precision on return types.

Comment: The original function triggers a `PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored` compilation error.

Comment: @user1844205 "PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored" is usually followed by another error saying why it was ignored. eg see answer..what do you get exactly?

Comment: Oh, then disregard my comment. The error is that I don't have such table :)

Comment: @user1844205 ok then that would certainly cause it :)

Comment: Thank you ...it is solved I removed the precision from my datatype